# Weblogic 12.2.1.1: deployment error

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, validation, weblogic12c

**Log:**

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)

I think it is related to javax.validation api, I tried with 1.0 and 1.1, both are failing

**The same WAR file runs fine in Weblogic 10.3.6.**
Below is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.maven.artifact.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.maven.artifact.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.batch.core.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</spring.batch.core.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <jbehave.version>3.9.5</jbehave.version>
    <jbehave.web.selenium.version>3.5.5</jbehave.web.selenium.version>
    <validation.api.version>1.0.0.GA</validation.api.version>
    <hibernate.validator.version>4.3.2.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <joda.time.version>2.7</joda.time.version>
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.3.2</hsqldb.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
    <xstream.version>1.4.8</xstream.version>
    <commons.jxpath.version>1.3</commons.jxpath.version>
    <commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>
    <commons.lang.version>2.6</commons.lang.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>
    <apache.poi.version>3.9</apache.poi.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Audit trail xpath queries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.jxpath.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test specific jars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
        <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
        <version>${vividsolutions.jts.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- test scoped dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.maven.artifact.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSR-303 standard Java Bean Validation annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${validation.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda.time.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.grundid.opendatalab</groupId>
        <artifactId>geojson-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is my weblogic.xml

```
<weblogic-web-app>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <session-monitoring-enabled>true</session-monitoring-enabled>
        <servlet-reload-check-secs>-1</servlet-reload-check-secs>
    </container-descriptor>
    <context-root>business-services</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Kindly help me to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved.

I have upgraded the hibernate.validator version to 5.3.0.Final and validation.api version to 1.1.0.Final.

Weblogic 12.2.1.1 only support Validator api 1.1.0 and corresponding Hibernate validator version is 5.3.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

2.x versions has the method you are looking for

[Reference to source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.hk2.external/bean-validator-cdi/2.1.96/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/ConfigurationImpl.java#ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider%28%29)

Comment: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl this class is there in all the versions.

Comment: but getDefaultParameterNameProvider method doesn't contains in every version.

Comment: This issue is resolved by updating the validator api and hibernate validator versions, but you made me go in the correct direction, hibernate validator version 5.3.0 has getDefaultParameterNameProvider method. Thanks a lot.